# iCloud on a broken device

Tags: iphone, icloud

So two days ago, i dropped my (already cracked) iPhone 6 in water, and it was in there for over a minute. I ran home and in less than 5 minutes, it was in rice. After 24 hours, i tried turning it on, nothing happened. I tried charging it for about ten minutes, and nothing was happening, so i put it back in rice. And although how to fix my phone would be helpful to know, that's not my question. Ir seems pretty hopeless to recover the phone, I am a photographer and just want to know how to get the photos and videos off of there. I have iCloud turned o on it, but i am 95% positive i turned off photo sharing. Is there any way I can still recover the photos? My life will be ruined if I can't, i love my phone more than my family and don't know what to do. Any suggestions? (or just how to get the phone working again)

Comment: If it won't turn on and the battery's dead...there's not much that can be done.

Comment: Plug it into a computer and see if it comes up, probably won't work but might as well give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

If you have iCloud backup and iCloud photos/Photo Stream turned on then the photos should be accessible to you when you restore your new phone from iCloud.

Photo Stream should also be available to you if you have iCloud photos turned on via icloud.com.

If not you may have to see if Apple or a 3rd-party repair shop can get your old phone working to get the pics off of it.